# Passing null-terminated unicode string to method DRMSetRevocationPoint

Tags: c++, rms

I'm using Microsoft's AD RMS SDK to perform document encryption and revocation of user rights.

To perform revocation I need to use the method [DRMSetRevocationPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . I need to pass in the Public Key I've used in signing an XML revocation list (the list has been created, and signed).  The argument is a PWSTR so I've tried passing the value of the public key that I see in the XML but I think it's incorrect (receiving an error when the list is called from Office).  What I'm after is the correct way to pass the key to this method.  I've found that in documentation for (similar) methods in the SDK this argument is documented in the following ways:

wszPublicKey in DRMGetRevocationPoint:

> *A pointer to a null-terminated Unicode string that receives the optional public key to identify a revocation list outside the
>   content's chain of trust. The size of this buffer is specified by the
>   puPublicKeyLength parameter.*

wszPublicKey in DRMSetUsagePolicy:

> *A pointer to a null-terminated Unicode string that contains the public key used to sign the digest of the application required to or
>   prohibited from exercising rights. This string must be a well-formed
>   XrML node. This parameter is required when eUsagePolicyType contains
>   DRM_USAGEPOLICY_TYPE_BYPUBLICKEY. It is ignored for all other
>   eUsagePolicyType values.*

I'm looking at the documentation of this field on these methods as they have a bit more to go on.  What I'm after is the correct way to take the key I have and push it into the method - any advice would be great.  The public key from the signed revocation list is as follows:

```
<PUBLICKEY>
<ALGORITHM>RSA</ALGORITHM> 
<PARAMETER name="public-exponent">
<VALUE encoding="integer32">65537</VALUE> 
</PARAMETER>
<PARAMETER name="modulus">
<VALUE encoding="base64" size="1024">8Rk8Gx2bG6ML5y/RDjyHpFwhU0g/JYNOpewEsAMw+SndTaWCAPRDZr+NVzOorrBcycVenJd9XupQndStvDN0dID+nVAL8ZwCaFtzcW74g9YRDlHWnld1SOo7VysXKC3mkLvl64CPQMzM1MlmLZ3J9vkCpiOYV/8Xu0lAcpbRdLg=</VALUE> 
</PARAMETER>
</PUBLICKEY>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any code, but a PWSTR is a wchar_t pointer, which on Windows is a Unicode (UTF-16) string (of wchar_t characters). To do this with a string literal you need to put an `L` before the string, i.e. `L"Hello world"`, but if you're doing this in code you want something like a `std::wstring` and to use its `c_str()` member to obtain the pointer.